# In a DOS script, is there a way to verify a string exists within a variable?

Tags: windows, powershell, dos

In a DOS script, if I have a variable string, how do I get a true or false that a certain string exists within that variable string?  ( I don't want to have to create a temp file to accomplish this. I know how to do that hack already.)  FIND.exe and FINDSTR.exe both seem to require a physical file rather than a variable.

I tried this, but it fails:

```
C:\Users\me>findstr.exe "Program" %ProgramData%
```

Comment: Do you literally mean a DOS script? Or do you mean a Windows CMD shell script?

Comment: Hmm. I see now that you've tagged your question `powershell`. That is something else entirely. Please clarify what sort of shell/script you're dealing with.

Comment: I tagged as Powershell because I know that Powershell programmers have a lot of DOS script knowledge.  It seems I was right on this assumption as I got a quick answer from one of them and it helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to use a stock windows install - I don't think this can be accomplished as you describe using CMD.EXE as the closest you will get would be with the `IF` command, but it doesn't support a contains, it only contains the following operators:

```
EQU - equal
NEQ - not equal
LSS - less than
LEQ - less than or equal
GTR - greater than
GEQ - greater than or equal
```

If you can get away with what you want to do using those operators (and not strictly just a contains). You can also use the `FOR` command to split your string and test your matches on each individual element, though that seems rather brittle.

Since you have tagged this as PowerShell, I am going to go out on a limb and assume that a PowerShell script solution would be acceptable as well. If that is the case, then the solution is quite simple to demonstrate:

```
# create a variable $s with some string data
$s = "Some random program data"

# using String::Contains
if ($s.Contains("random")) { "Bingo" }

# using -like operator
if ($s -like "*random*") { "Bingo" }

# using the -match operator
if ($s -match "random") { "Bingo" }
```

Note: In PowerShell, the `-contains` operator is used to test for set membership, not substring matching. You will want to use the `Contains` method on a string object or the `-like` or `-match` operators to perform the desired patter matching.

Comment: Thanks, that answers my question well enough.  I was hoping for an actual way to do this but since my string is space-delimmetted, I think I can use your suggestion of using the FOR loop to parse it out and compare each token.   Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found another idea in the DOSTIPS forum:

```
set "str=-debug -verbose -normi -homedir -repo"
if "%str:-verbose=%" neq "%str%" (echo -verbose found) else (echo -verbose not found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
C:\Users\me>findstr.exe "Program" %ProgramData%
```

try

```
echo %ProgramData% | findstr Program >nul
set RESULT=%ERRORLEVEL%
```

If it matches, %ERRORLEVEL% will be 0, otherwise, 1.